# Tracking Click to Call

Tags: href, tel, utm

How can I track a phone number with UTM parameters?

```
<a href="tel:18001234567">Call Me</a>
```

I tried adding ?utm_content=bannerctc like so:

```
<a href="tel:18001234567?utm_content=bannerctc">Call Me</a>
```

But this just converts the letters into numbers so it tries to call: 18001234567?886_2668368=754332

Here is the catch. I'd like to fix this without any javascript or PHP, our CMS platform is crap and is blocking us from using Js or any other programming languages.

I thought of using a redirect as a "middle man" so from the click to call link send users to a bitly url that redirects people to the phone number but I am not sure that would work...

Any help, please?

Thanks,